# Apostrophe after Proper Noun ending with s

Tags: apostrophe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the correct possessive for nouns ending in s?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1073/what-is-the-correct-possessive-for-nouns-ending-in-s)
>   [When did it become correct to add an 's' to a singular possessive already ending in 's'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2964/when-did-it-become-correct-to-add-an-s-to-a-singular-possessive-already-ending)

Today's Newyorker News Desk says Texas's insurgent establishment.
Is *Texas's* correct usage? Doesn't seem elegant in any case.

Comment: Perhaps not elegant, but as a Texan, I assure you it is correct. :)

Comment: Also related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63199/achilles-heel-and-achilles-tendon

Comment: If you like, you can also consider 'Ayers Rock'. It's about 200miles from Alice Springs (Australia).

Answer (score 0):

I agree it's not very elegant, but it is generally considered acceptable. If you don't like it, you can of course write *Texas'* as you would expect. And it's usually possible to rewrite your sentence to avoid the issue if you're feeling paranoid about receiving a deluge of pedantry.

Comment: Note that writing *Texas’* is considered unacceptable by some publishers.

Comment: I dare say... On the other hand, they'll then have in-house pedants to resolve such issues so you don't usually need to worry.