# Not pronouncing the end of a possessive construction

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling

Everyone knows the rule (not universally followed) that when a word ends with the letter S, we just add an apostrophe right after the word, instead of adding an apostrophe and an S after it. So, according to the above rule of thumb, it's

> Mary's book
>
> Johns' wife
>
> Mike's pencil
>
> Copernicus' theory

The noun itself is pronounced fully with an S at the end, and then the S sound is pronounced immediately.

But there's another category of words that end with an S - i.e. most plurals. In this case, at least in writing, we (again, not universally) follow the same rule:

> April Fools' Day
>
> Mathematicians' paradise
>
> Parents' house

But I have noted that in the second case, the missing S after the apostrophe is not pronounced at all, even in formal speech.

**Is this normal?**

Comment: Are you asking about (e.g.) /*parents*/ vs /*parentses*/ in the pronunciation?

Comment: @Lawrence that's exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: Indeed, the apostrophe is not pronounced. Just like in _it's_, _isn't_, _doesn't_, etc.

Comment: **Johns'** wife? How many is she married to?

Comment: Do a site search (top right corner) for [plural possessive pronunciation](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=plural+possessive+pronunciation). There are several posts that you might find helpful on the topic.

Comment: @oerkelens of course it's not, I meant something completely different, indeed. Fixed it.

Comment: @AndrewLeach here _Johns_ is a last name, so one husband only.

Comment: Something completely different? Like why the _s_ that's not there is not pronounced? The fact that is is not written is a good indication that it shouldn't be pronounced either. Spelling normally follows speech, after all. Just like the omitted _O_ in my earlies examples (from _not_) is not pronounced when it's omitted.

Comment: @oerkelens but in my experience if the noun is singular and ends with an S, the additional S after the apostrophe _is_ pronounced, though usually not written.

Comment: @MichaelSmith That’s because people don’t know how to spell properly, nothing else. Those are spelling mistakes by the unlettered.

Comment: Acoording to [what I can find](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/possessive-of-proper-names-ending-in-s/), if you pronounce it, you write it.

Comment: @oerkelens I've come to the conclusion that the rule "if you pronounce it, you write it" makes the most amount of sense. If you post an answer elaborating just a bit, I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: @MichaelSmith Then you should mark [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/89705/2085) or [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/79083/2085) instead, because if that’s what you’re looking for, you’ve asked an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

You have the rule wrong. The rule is that the possessive and the plural inflexions sound the same, and so if both inflexions are present they are indistinguishable by ear. They do not accumulate: down that road lie Gollum’s rustic *fisheses*.

The plural of *Copernicus* is *Copernicuses**, which means you add another syllable and a new /z/ sound at the end.

The possessive therefore does the same thing phonologically and so must be written *Copernicus’s* to match, which is indistinguishable in sound from the plural *Copernicuses*.

That’s why the plural of *farmer* is *farmers*, which sounds exactly the same as *farmer’s*  It’s also why the possessive plural is *farmers’*, which is indistinguishable in sound from *farmers* and *farmer’s*.

---

- <sub>I’m of course talking English here. If it were Latin, then the plural of *Copernicus* would be *Copernici*. Then again, the possessive would then also be *Copernici*, and so the possessive singular and the plural would still be the same, just like how in English they are the same, at least aurally. Latin has its own possessive plural *Copernicorum*, so belonging to a bunch of *Copernici*. English has no special plural possessive, however, and so we would talk about all of the many Copernicuses’ various individual achievements.</sub>

Comment: Ah, it's been a while since I've seen one of your very welcome answers. +1.

Comment: Thanks for including the addendum about the Latin; it was very interesting