# men's vs mens which is correct

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, possessives

I am working on an invitation design for a charity. I am wondering which one of these is correct, Young Men's Committee or Young Mens Committee

Comment: @sumelic Not so much a duplicate, but definitely answers the question.

Answer (score -1):

Duplicate of: [Is "mens" a valid word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112420/is-mens-a-valid-word/112422#112422)

I added to the top answer in the link above, but it's still being peer reviewed, this is what I wrote:

> In old English, plurals were formed with "en": brethren, men, women,
>   children, chicken.
>
> Most of these words except 'brethren' (it is more common to use '2
>   brothers' instead of '2 brethren')
>
> To show possession of these particular plural words, the correct way
>   would be to treat them as singular:
>
> Men's wear
>
> Children's wear

Source:
http://crofsblogs.typepad.com/english/2007/07/mens-or-mens.html

@published is incorrect, but the confusion is understandable.

Answer (score -3):

In this case, the apostrophe serves little purpose and can be a little confusing since it hints at the men owning the committee.  I'd leave it out.

Comment: The apostrophe shows that it's a committee *of* or *for* young men. Please list a reference showing that "mens" is a word, and what it means.