# How to determine if I should use "St." or "Saint"?

Tags: word-choice, abbreviations

I'm referring specifically to city names, though I suppose this applies to other things named after saints.

I'm looking at the Wikipedia pages for my "sources of truth". [Saint Paul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Paul,_Minnesota) is fairly split, with 170 instances of "Saint Paul" and 40 instances of "St. Paul".

[St. Louis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Louis), however, is almost always St. Louis, with only 5 instances of "Saint Louis" and 460 instances of "St. Louis".

I'm looking for any semblance of rhyme or reason here, but I can't seem to find any documentation on this.

I thought it might be official names, but it appears [Saint Augustine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Augustine,_Florida) is officially "City of Saint Augustine", but the text for the page only includes that 4 times (compared to 139), and none of those are in the actual text.

Comment: [This answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/2641/142322) indicates that once a place name is set (whether for a road or city, etc), it becomes simply a set of characters forming that name. There is no further rhyme or reason other than history for the way it is spelt.

Comment: I want to "I will edit to explain how" but I actually don't really see any similarities. I vaguely see what you're saying with your first comment, but I definitely don't think the answer to that question in any way answers my question any more than it just "informs it".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*St.*, like *Mt.* or *Ft.* or less commonly *Ctr.*, *Spgs.*, *Hts.*, and so on, are just abbreviations. While it is less common to see *Sault Sainte Marie* as opposed to *Sault Ste. Marie*, it is not "incorrect" to write it out as such, and for the most part, you can expect official laws and documents to write out the name in full.

How *you* should represent the name of a place is a matter of style. Adhere to the discipline of your editor, publication, or organization, or in the absence of a house style, adopt a [style manual](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2579/16052) appropriate to your audience and tastes and be consistent in its application.

According to the Chicago Manual of Style, for example,

> Prefixes of most geographic names should not be abbreviated in text:
>
> > ```
> > Fort Wayne      Mount Airy    South Orange
> > Saint Cloud     San Diego     Port Arthur
> > ```
>
> Many editors make an exception for names beginning with *Saint* (St. Louis, St. Lawrence), and where space must be saved any such prefixes (except *San*, *Santa*, etc.) may be abbreviated (*Ft., Pt., Mt., S.* [*South*], etc.).

For an alternative view, the AP Stylebook (2013) states

> **saint** Abbreviate as *St.* in the names of saints, cities and other places: *St. Jude*; *St. Paul, Minn.*; *St. John's, Newfoundland*; *St. Lawrence Seaway*
>
> But see the entries for **Saint John** and **Sault Ste. Marie**
>
> **Saint John** The spelling for the city in New Brunswick, to distinguish it from *St. John's, Newfoundland*

This contrasts with the AP guidance for *fort* and *mount*, which are never to be abbreviated.

These do suggest that for a large proportion of American writing, at least, *St.* is a much more common and acceptable abbreviation than the others in running text.

A single Wikipedia article will not be a reliable guide to usage. The local newspaper is the *St. Paul Pioneer Press*—

[image: St. Paul Pioneer Press front page]

and the abbreviated form is also used by the [state tourism board](http://www.exploreminnesota.com/where-to-go/minneapolis-st-paul-area/), the [airport](https://www.mspairport.com/about-msp), the [independent baseball team](http://saintsbaseball.com/), and so on. For that matter, the [Wikipedia discussion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Saint_Paul,_Minnesota) on the name points out that both *St. Paul* and *Saint Paul* have widespread usage, and "It's almost always useless to debate orthography in this manner."